# Clickhouse topK query on several columns

Tags: olap, clickhouse

In ClickHouse, is there any way use the topK query on more than the column ,

for example:

```sql
select topK(10)(AGE,COUNTRY) ...
```

meaning I want the top10 combinations of AGE+COUNTRY, 
I only found a workaround using *concat* on fields and topK on them, wondered if there is any other way.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass array (or tuple) of columns to [topK](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#topk-n-column):

```sql
SELECT topK(10)([Age, Country])
FROM table
```

Or use the straightforward calculation (it is much slower but provides the exact result):

```sql
SELECT
    Age,
    Country
FROM table
GROUP BY
    Age,
    Country
ORDER BY count() DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir

The reason I was searching specifically for a topK solution was because it seems to perform much better than count+order by, when using few CH instances, Is it because count will cause the entire data to be shuffled from the servers to the coordinator ?

Comment: No problem, I glad to help you. The second query I added just for information, it works much slowly but gives the exact result. The first query is the recommended way - it is the fastest but don't provide a guaranteed result (see description [here](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#topk-n-column)).